# How to connect smack client to ejabberd Server with SSL

Tags: java, ssl, ejabberd, smack, asmack

I am trying to connect ejabberd server from smack client with SSL. I got SSL certificate and I successfully configure https on ejabberd. Whenever i try to connect with ejabber with http from smack, i got success. But when i enabled https in ejabberd and try to connect, i got error: 
                     **"Hostname verification of certificate failed. Certificate does not authenticate"**

Java code with smack is:

```
    config=XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    //config.setUsernameAndPassword("ramsey", "123");
    config.setResource("smack");
    config.setServiceName("*MY Domain*");
    config.setHost("*MY Domain*");
    config.setPort(5222);

    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.ifpossible);
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[]{new TLSUtils.AcceptAllTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
    config.setCustomSSLContext(sc);

    conn = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());

    conn.connect();
```

There is need to add certificate in Java code. please give me some suggestions or reference link.

Comment: check this link may help you - https://github.com/ge0rg/MemorizingTrustManager

Comment: I tried this one but not getting success. I want Java code with smack library. Key-store is generated with key-tool and try to connect with smack code. I got error  "No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'." Please give some suggestion.

Comment: ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.ifpossible sometimes if not configured like this in server side client will always fail when login. If ssl is disable server side do the same in client side